# Receiving Touch Events from a Service

Tags: android, service, touch-event

I am currently working on recieving touch events from a service.

One way I thought to do this was to use a TouchDelegate on a system view, extend its bounds to the screen, and then receive touch events from within the delegate.

However, when I use

```
((Activity)ctx).getWindow().getDecorView().setTouchDelegate(new TouchDel(bounds, view));
```

from within my service I get a nullpointerexception and a force close.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no mechanism by which a `Service` could be directly registered to globally receive touch events from the system.  The `Activity` UI in your application would need to hand the events it receives down to your `Service`.  Without knowing more about the specific use you have for them, I can only suggest a generic approach.  One such possible approach might be:

- In your `Activity` classes, override `dispatchTouchEvent()` to be notified of each event as it is sent to your application.  Be careful not to override the return behavior, which will disrupt the touch handling in your views.
- `MotionEvent` is `Parcelable`, so you could package each event up in an `Intent` and send them as start commands to your `Service`.
- Alternately, implement your `Service` as a bound service so each `Activity` in your application can bind to it and call methods directly, and have each `MotionEvent` passed that way.

Comment: But what about receiving touch events outside of an activity, such as on the home screen? An activity is a screen and Activity.dispatchTouchEvent() is a method which would return touch events dispatch only to that activity. As soon as the activity is off the screen, it can't continue to receive touch events.

Comment: Receiving any events outside the context of your application is not supported in Android by design.  Even a Service, which may not be in front of the user, is still bound by the context of your application's process.  Adding such functionality would require modifications of the Android system services/kernel in a custom ROM image.